# laravel 4 across 2 Eloquent with scope

Tags: model, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel, Thanks for helping

I had two Eloquent models, Job and User

The Job Model as follows:

```
<?php
class Job extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'tbl_jobs';

  public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User','uid');
  }

  public function scopeWork($query) {
    return $query->where('worktime', '=', 0); 
  }
}
```

and the User Model is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {
  protected $table = 'tbl_users';

  public function scopeActive($query) {
    return $query->where('status', '=', 'Active'); 
  }
}
```

The Question is How can I call both models with scope(Active and Work) in one statements?
or some thing like

```
    Job::Work()->with('user')->get();
```

is that belongsTo is not equal to inner join??

Comment: No, with() is not joining anything. So the question is: do you want to get models intersection (Job scope AND User scope) or get Job in scope, and then add related Users that match scope (or not add if they don't) - the latter may result in Job without users, while first can't

Comment: Thank you, deczo, I want to get models intersection both Work scope and Active scope, that means I want to get the tbl_jobs.worktime = 0 and tbl_users.status = 'active', how can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For intersection you need this:

```
Job::work()     // apply scope on jobs
  ->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
    // apply users scope to get only jobs with active users
    $q->active();

})->with(['users' => function ($q) {
    // apply scope on users' eager loading to load only active 
    $q->active();

})->get();
```

Comment: WhereHas - does not use index, can we use Join instead?

Comment: If you see the need b/c of the performance issue, then use `join`. Eloquent `whereHas` and a few other sweets are there just to make your life easier, and the code more portable, but definitely sometimes you can notice the drawback, that's worse performance.